# Burmese Fonts (@font-face) not displaying correction on Android Phone Galaxy S3 with firmware (4.1.2)

Tags: android, font-face, android-4.2-jelly-bean, html-rendering, woff

I tested my blog in Burmese using @font-face. It works well on, Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari. I tested with Window, Mac, iPhone and Galaxy S3 (Jelly Bean 4.1.2).

I found out that every devices display font very well except the Android device. Obviously, the android phone downloads the web font. It displays the font though. It just doesn’t show right.

I use ‘Tharlon’ font from Google font API early access.

My blog ID is http://www.constructionforum-myanmar.com/

I’m not a geek. I’m just a professional from Construction industry who wants to shear my experience and knowledge.  I read here and there about coding and wrote this blog and I want it to be able to read on all devices. Burmese font is not displaying on all device though.

Could you please help me? What should I do to solve this font problem on Android.

Answer (score 1):

After all I found out that it works well on other Andriod phones such as HTC One and earlier version for firmware for Galaxy S.

The problem is firmware version (4.1.2) for Galaxy S doesn't render Burmese (Myanmar) font properly.

Comment: I did more research though. I found that Android devices does not support Indic Unicode. The issue was well explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300391/unicode-support-for-android