# unicode characters in android

Tags: android, unicode, ime

A local phone distributor asks me he wants unicode characters of a country to be built-in their android supported phone. This Unicode characters were not supported in previous versions before lollipop, in previous version before lollipop if we want to use this unicode characters we have to get root access and we have to add font to android system file and keyboard too. His requirement is asking me to add this Unicode characters in their firmware, so no need to root. Some phone manufacturer such as Samsung, HTC and Huawei provide that Unicode character without root access. When I am surfing in google how did they do I found this link [Unicode support for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300391/unicode-support-for-android). I don’t much about android os, but I know I have to deeply understand of how android system works if I want to add this Unicode characters in firmware. I would be pleased greatly if someone clarifies my question.

Comment: This is a font installation issue, not a coding issue.  All you have to do is install an appropriate font onto the device, and how you do that is outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10051942/65863 if you want to use a custom font in an application without actually install the font on the device. But if you need to use the font in multiple apps, system keyboard, etc, then you have to install it.