# Not show symbol "₺" on Android 4.4. (KitKat)

Tags: android

```
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/salesEarnedValueTextView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:text="Test symbol ₺"
 android:textColor="#2c3939"
 android:textSize="23sp"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/earnedDividerView"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

As result on Android 5+ text success show "**Test symbol ₺**". OK.

But on Android 4.4. show only "**Test symbol** " . Not show symbol **₺**

Comment: try to use by textView.setText("Test symbol ₺");

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300391/unicode-support-for-android#10378910

Comment: have you tried setting your font to a font that supports unicode characters?

Answer (score 1):

By default Android uses Roboto typeface and different Android versions may use different typeface versions with different symbols set. So to support some specific symbols (like '₺' or '₽') at all devices you have to include latest Roboto font and use it like this

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Medium.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: You may download latest roboto here https://github.com/google/roboto/releases 
And check supported symbols here http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/

Answer (score 0):

Yes better to find a font that supports that symbol and set the text to that custom typeface. Maybe this can help:
[How to use custom font in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588965/how-to-use-custom-font-in-android-studio#)

Comment: No you are wrong. Look at the code in the best answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.